# Removing special chars from URL with .htaccess

Tags: windows, apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to use urls on my site like `example.com/@lorem-ipsum-dolor` instead of `example.com/tag/lorem-ipsum-dolor` form.

It's working on my local and remote servers, but if urls contains `" : \ * |` etc chars it's not working on local server (Win XP).

1. Is there any solution?
2. If not, then I think I need to remove that chars from url on local server. I googled for this a lot, but no result properly.

Any idea?

Comment: Do they get to your site or does it stop before then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those characters are *not* allowed in URLs. This really matters: Your URLs will fail validations and are likely to cause technical problems, because characters like `@` and `:` are used elsewhere in a valid URL.

From [RFC 2396](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt) via  [this SO question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37596/please-consider-s-plusses-valid-characters-in-the-seo-part-of-the-url/37622#37622):

> Many URI include components consisting of or delimited by, certain
>      special characters.  These characters are called "reserved", since
>      their usage within the URI component is limited to their reserved
>      purpose.  If the data for a URI component would conflict with the
>      reserved purpose, then the conflicting data must be escaped before
>      forming the URI.

```
  reserved    = ";" | "/" | "?" | ":" | "@" | "&" | "=" | "+" |
                "$" | ","
```

Comment: Thanks for answering Pekka.

So, is there any problem in this case?

I mean search engine problems, cos I moved all my URL's (maybe thousands) permanently with 301 header code and Google already changed them.

Comment: @qeremy chances are that your URLs work in all major browsers, but I would recommend changing them in the long run to avoid problems.

Comment: @qeremy I guess though that if Google already has them indexed, you won't have any search engine trouble.

Comment: Great! You saved me from a big confusion. 
I was wondering for this, cos my site just released out from Google Sandbox and I really don't want SE problems anymore.
Danke schön!